# Is there a way to reference one function parameter from another function parameter in python?

Tags: python, numpy

There may be a better way to do this, and if there is I'm all ears. But I am trying to write a function that takes a `numpy` array of arbitrary size and reduces it using `Gauss-Jordan Elimination`. I would like to create an augmented matrix with the passed matrix A on the left and either a default column vector of zeros or a user specified column vector on the right. In other words, for a matrix A and column vector b I could define my function like:

```py
def gauss_jordan(A, b=np.zeros((A.shape[0],1)):
    # Do stuff here
```

Unfortunately, when I try to reference the first parameter `A` in the second parameter `b` it tells me it is not defined. Is there a way to reference the first passed parameter from the second parameter? Or is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:
Doing as Tim suggested:

I get the following error when trying to pass a user defined vector `b`.

> **ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**

I had tried the `true/false` route before but ran into the same problem.

EDIT 2:
Thanks all! I got it working properly with the following. The "is" operator slipped my mind. I added the reshape after the else so that it is returned as a column vector.

```
def gauss_jordan(A, b=None):
    rows, columns = A.shape
    
    if b is None:
        b = np.zeros((rows,1))
    else:
        b = b.reshape((rows,1))

    # Do other stuff
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `b=None`, it safest to do a `b is None` test:

```
In [47]: def foo(A, b=None):
    ...:     if b is None:
    ...:         b = np.zeros((A.shape[0],1))
    ...:     return b.shape
    ...: 
In [48]: foo(np.arange(3))
Out[48]: (3, 1)
In [49]: foo(np.arange(3),np.zeros(10))
Out[49]: (10,)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not in this fashion, no.  The default value is resolved when the function is defined.  `A` has no bound value until the call, much later.  In this case, your proper flow of data is as given in Tim's answer: provide an obviously "not supplied" value; test-and-set `b` as soon as you enter the function.  This gives you the binding you want, consistent with Python language definition.

Here is a simple proof-of-concept:

```
def gj(A, b=None):
    b = b or len(A)
    print (A, b)

gj("Hello, world")
gj("Hello, world", 1729)
```

Output:

```
Hello, world 12
Hello, world 1729
```

Comment: Commenting here too so that you see it. The problem is the true/false tries to compare all values in the array. I get the following error - ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: You get the ambiguity error when you pass `b` as an array, the `np.zeros(...)`.  If instead you pass a shape, e.g `b=len(a)` it should be ok.  Rather than use `or`, test  `b is None`.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not support references to earlier function parameters in default value definitions. The Pythonic solution here is probably to use a default argument of `None`:

```
def gauss_jordan(A, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = np.zeros((A.shape[0],1)
    # Do stuff here
```

Comment: I get the following error - ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: fixed to explicitly check for None.